# Enable button when form is valid

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I Want the button that submit form just stay enabled when the form is valid:

```
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="submitForm(data)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
  Salvar
</button>

<form name="myForm">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da categoria" ng-model="data.Categoria.name" required>
   </label>
</form>
```

I think the issue is the button is before form so they are not "seeing" myForm.$invalid. If you ask me why I cant put button inside form, is because this button is on bar header of the app and the form is bellow.

How can I handle this situation??

Comment: That's not the case myForm would be available at button scope level, if it as above. if it is in a different template it may not be available.

Comment: Whats not working? And, can't you declare the form up in the header and close it where it closed right now? Is everything is within the ng-controller scope?

Comment: Is everything in the same template and in the same controller.. I follow your idea and put <form> in the beginning of the page to wrap the button too. If you set the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-form directive. [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

```
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="submitForm(data)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
       Salvar
  </button>

  <div data-ng-form name="myForm">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da categoria" ng-model="data.Categoria.name" required>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can both try by setting the form including both controls:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="submitForm(data)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
    Salvar
  </button>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da categoria" ng-model="data.Categoria.name" required>
   </label>
</form>
```

Or in cases where you don't want to break the layout or don't need a form, with [ng-form directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm):

```
<div class="item item-input-inset" ng-form="myForm">
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="submitForm(data)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
    Salvar
  </button>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da categoria" ng-model="data.Categoria.name" required>
   </label>
</div>
```